# Use multiple indicators for predictions using Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, data-science

The program I am using deals with just the opening column of the apple stock (from yahoo finance).

Basically I want to add other columns into the model to add some complexity into my model. For example, look at the High for the day or even the close of the day.

How do I do this. Do I just change this code below:

```
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
```

To

```
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], #2 or 3 etc.)))
```

If so does this mean I change the processed data set from:

```
data_training_processed = data_training_complete.loc[:, ['Open']].values
```

To

```
data_training_processed = data_training_complete.loc[:, ['Open']['High'].values #adding as much as neccessary
```

If I want to include High into the model.

Answer (score 0):

It remains

```
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
```

Because the additional column is already automatically processed correctly by `X_train.shape[1]` (which will be one higher).

And

```
data_training_processed = data_training_complete.loc[:, ['Open', 'High']].values
```

Comment: Thanks, So the 3D matrix, what does the 2nd dimension do if we ever include it?

Comment: Welcome. It is the "color" dimension - also called "channel". Used when your input is an overlay of different "colors" (e.g. [red, green, blue] values e.g. or whatever. - please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful ;) .

Comment: I am  getting an error with this line of code ```data_total = pd.concat((data_training_complete['Open','High'], data_test_complete['Open','High']), axis = 0)``` saying Key Error

Comment: For LSTM, input shape simply means `(timesteps, num_features)`.  OP wants to increase `num_features` as he's trying to include other OHLC values in training and prediction.

Comment: @frogatto Yes, thats the plan I am hoping for. Is my way the correct way?

Comment: @frogatto thanks. You are right. but still `X_train.shape[1]` will automatically increase by one.

Comment: @user218030 You have to put `time_steps` in front of it. I corrected in my answer. - and you can have only some error. You have to take care what you are indexing at all. You have to learn basics of pandas and numpy it seems. I recommend you Corey Schafer's tutorials in youtube.

Comment: @Gwang-jin kim I am confused a bit. I have a shape of (1260,2) which is correct for my array (with open and high features), But When converting to the 3D array, does the first dimension contain the first feature array and the second dimension the 2nd feature.

Comment: @user218030 Maybe a minimal working example will help us to help you. Just if you create an example train data set of first 3 samples for x and y? Because it is a little bit abstract at the moment. I mean code to create `data_training_complete` with first 3 samples - and corresponding labels/targets. And a minimal model with the LSTM layer and maybe one Dense layer if you use them and the output layer.